# How to put security in nginx server throughput LDAP server to LDAP users?

Tags: html, authentication, nginx, ldap

I would like to put authentication and security in my nginx server with my LDAP users that they are in a LDAP server.

I have not idea about this. Knows somebody how to implement the security in nginx server using LDAP server so in this way restrict the view of my html pages by everybody and only to LDAP users.